# Synapse does not show folders

Tags: directory, synapse

I recently installed synapse to compare it to gnome-do. But except for the home folder, synapse does not show any folder on my system - even if I type the exact name of that folder. gnome-do shows all folders I need. 
Is this a bug or is this intended? On the other hand, I have the synapse "directory search"-plug-in running.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This resolved the issue:

```
zeitgeist-daemon --quit
rm -rvf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index/
zeitgeist-daemon --replace
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Any ideas as to why the "Directory Search" plugin doesn't work?  It seems it should be able to find directories with or without Zeitgeist, but it doesn't (beyond the home directory).

Comment: no ideas. I haven't had any issues with synapse ever since - but now I'm on 13.10 and zeitgeist and synapse have seen some changes in the last 2 years...

Comment: The one description of the plugin says "Open commonly used directories", so it probably depends on Zeitgeist.