# Synapse STILL does not show files or folders

Tags: 12.04, synapse

I have a problem that been [reported before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87960/synapse-does-not-show-folders) but the solution on that page has not helped me at all. Basically, Synapse can't find ANY* files or folders other than "Home" and I've never been able to figure out why. This means I am limited to using it to open apps. When I want to find a file or folder, I still have to navigate to get to what I'm looking for. And I've finally had enough!

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on three machines (a laptop, a desktop, and a VM) with Cinnamon (edit: Unity too), and Synapse doesn't find files or folders other than "Home" on ANY of them. This has been driving me crazy for so long, and I keep coming across [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87960/synapse-does-not-show-folders) every time I try to solve it, but it just doesn't work.

Footnote: **Correction** - Synapse can find *some* files (but very few), and no folders other than home.

**UPDATE**: Seriously, people. Nothing? Nada? Not even a wild guess? If it doesn't work on multiple machines for me I can't imagine no one else has had this issue! I was thinking maybe Spideroak or Dropbox was interfering, but I disabled them and ran the zeitgeist commands in the linked page, and still nothing! Gaaa! I feel like I'm living in the stone age without this!

Comment: Have this problem as well; enabling Zeitgeist can help, but that damn "Directory Search" plugin should be enough here (but is not working).

Comment: @limist Well at least SOMEBODY made some sort of comment or reply here. I STILL haven't solved the issue, and I was beginning to wonder why nobody else seems to be dealing with it. At least I know I'm not alone, or crazy.

Comment: Seems that newer versions of Ubuntu and Synapse don't have this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87960/synapse-does-not-show-folders/128684?noredirect=1#comment538569_128684
Maybe using the PPA to get a newer version is the solution: https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.
What improved the situation for me was to disable all zeitgeist-related plugins in synapse. 
Now, the locate plugin works.

Synapse seemed to be waiting forever answers from some of them, blocking the possibility to use the locate plugin, which usually is sufficient for me.

This solution is not perfect, since zeitgeist often gives better results (what was accessed last etc.),
but at least Synapse is useful again.